# ASP.Net - How to access Session object out side code-behind file

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to get info from Session object and update some info from a class library.
How can I access Session in library?

Comment: Please promise me you won't do this. Please.

Comment: Try not to do this, this would create an implicit dependency on there being an HTTP session for your library to work.  You should really try to make this dependency explicit by requiring it to be passed into your library.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I want to manage Session using my class all over the project. SO that I can set some standard session elements. Do you think I should pass the session object to my class? Whats recommended way of doing this?

Comment: That is an entirely different (and more useful) question from what you asked =).  What kind of stuff do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @eFriend, please define what `manage Session` means. To me without more context it means nothing.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, in short I want to make a session wrapper class. Which will create/add/remove session variables.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I think he means manage access to it, probably something along the lines of [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/cstewart/archive/2008/01/09/strongly-typed-session-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: @R0MANARMY, yeah probably he means something along those lines.

Comment: @eFriend: In that case the approach described below is as good as anything.  This is probably something that will be internal to your app and not re-used anywhere else.  Generally the term *library* ends to mean something different from what you intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HttpContext Class (System.Web)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string mySessionVar = context.Session["my-session-var"];
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add a Reference to `System.Web.dll` in your class library project and then you can access your current session by `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`